# macosx lion bash tab completion for directories takes ages

Tags: tabs, osx-lion, bash-completion

At work, I have to wait 1s~5s for dir completion in iterm2. Same mba, but at home it works instantly.

Comment: Is there any chance that your work configuration involves something longer latency, like a slow NFS-mounted file system?  If this were the case, then you'd see the 1-5s delay on other kinds of file system access too, like running an ls command.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, ls performs instantly,
tried netstat and it shows surprisingly large number of connections to ports like 59991 or 65085, hmm, how could I tell which app is using that port?

Comment: Those are high-numbered ports, so it sounds like those are the ephemeral ports allocated on the client side on connection initiation.  It might be interesting to check the corresponding "Foreign Address" reported for each one by netstat.  You can tell which process opened the socket by running "lsof -i" or "lsof -i -n" (which may run faster by skipping reverse DNS lookups).

Comment: its all chrome, didn't recognize the 1e100.net domain on first sight
so nope, this was a false direction
is there same syscall log file where I could see what is happening when I wait for tab completion of directory?